# Как получить свойства товаров в корзине Bitrix?

Tags: битрикс

Нужно получить свойства товара в функции метода OnBeforeBasketUpdate. Я бы хотел получить свойства с помощью GetList, но мне не приходит PRODUCT_ID. Массив пустой.

```
AddEventHandler("sale", "OnBeforeBasketUpdate", "UpdateFakeAvailability");
function UpdateFakeAvailability($ID, &$arFields)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($arFields);
    echo "<pre>";
}
```

Comment: Так может не приходит потому что не срабатывает событие? Добавление товара в корзину не вызывает событие обновления. Обновление корзины - это пересчет вручную запушенный или обновление кол-ва одного из товаров в корзине.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db_res = CSaleBasket::GetPropsList(
        array(
                "SORT" => "ASC",
                "NAME" => "ASC"
            ),
        array("BASKET_ID" => $ID)
    );
while ($ar_res = $db_res->Fetch())
{
   echo $ar_res["NAME"]."=".$ar_res["VALUE"]."<br>";
}
```